# LEFT JOIN VS INNER JOIN condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

A query Joins two tables with LEFT JOIN. The table gets the same records with INNER JOIN in all cases, so what is the reason to use LEFT JOIN. Are their any cases where the records can be different or would the result will always be the same since we are using the second table condition in the where clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT TableA.col1, TableA.col2, TableA.col3, TableA.col4, TableB.col1,TableB.bcol5
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.col1 = TableB.col1          
WHERE
TableA.col2='007'
AND TableA.col3='ABCD'
AND TableB.bcol5='SAM'
```

Answer (score 3):

The condition on `Tableb.bcol5` turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  With your conditions, that is always true.  `b.col5` has a `NULL` value in non-matching rows and that fails the condition `b.bcol5 = 'SAM'`.  The `INNER JOIN` would never produce those rows.

Presumably you intend:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4, b.col1, b.bcol5
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN
     TableB b
     ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND b.bcol5 = 'SAM'        
WHERE a.col2 = '007' AND a.col3 = 'ABCD';
```

Comment: I did not intend the addition of b.col5 near ON as that would produce null values of b.col5. since as the condition is converting it to INNER JOIN , will use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT Join to be clear.